# Preserve number format when copying very many digits from a Text Box

Tags: excel, formatting, copy-paste, number-formatting

I have a long number in a Text Box:

```
032010203010301030103010300103010301032010101030103007
```

When I want to copy this number (Ctrl+c) into a cell, the number will be:

```
3.2010203010301E+52
```

I want the destination cell to have the original number format. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the receiving cell as Text and Paste into it with Paste Special, Text.

Answer (score -1):

```
Just right click on the cell and choose Format cell.
Change the format from General to Number with zero number of decimal      places.
**This sollution works also for other typer of formatting. For example    Custom with single 0 or Text.
**The number format does not affect the actual cell value, which is displayed in the formula bar.
**When Excel displays cell such ##### it means that cell is to narrow. Just make it wider.

Take help form this site
http://best-excel-tutorial.com/59-tips-and-tricks/188-disable-scientific-notation
```